# Actionscript 3 - Get a variable's value by string name

Tags: string, actionscript-3, var

I have found a similar question to this one, but the answers given don't work in my situation.
Let me explain:

I'm working on a visual novel styled textbox writer. The basic functionality goes: Read text from dynamic texfield 'dialogueText', store it as string, clear the textbox and add back the stored string character for character. It works perfectly, but I want the functionality to replace text between double parenthesis, e.g. ((playerName)), with the value of the variable specified in those parenthesis. Saving what's in between the parenthesis as string also works, but I yet have to find a way to print the value of the variable specified between the parenthesis.

Example:

```
var playerName:String = "Anon";

function playFrame(frame:String):Function {
   return function(evt:Event = null):void{
      ...
      dialogueLine = dialogueText.text;
      for(var i:int = 0; i < dialogueLine.split("((").length - 1; i++){
         var dialogueVar:String = dialogueLine.substring(dialogueLine.indexOf("((") + 2, dialogueLine.indexOf("))"));
         //dialogueVar now contains whatever variable name is specified between (( ))   
         dialogueLine = dialogueLine.split("((" + dialogueVar + "))").join(***);
         //In join, *** has to be something that uses dialogueVar to look up a variable with name 'dialogueVar' (e.g. playerName), and then give it's value (which in this case would be 'Anon')
      }
      dialogueText.text = "";
      ...
   }
}
```

I got recommended to use this[dialogueVar] for this, but upon using trace() to test this I get 'undefined'. Does anyone have an option that is not hardcoding a switch statement for every possible variable?

Comment: I strongly discourage the use of closures (unnamed unbound functions you can create inside other functions) because of several reasons. One of them, **this** reference, used inside the closure, points to who knows where exactly because the closure is not bound to any specific object.

Comment: Then, you need an object with is collection of all the variables you want like **var sessionVars:Object = {playerName:"Anon", playerGender:"F"};** then you get a variable with **var aValue:String = sessionVars[variableName];**

Comment: Reason I use a closure is because I have to be able to call playFrame with a specific parameter, namely 'next', 'prev' and the name of a frame label to jump to. For as far as I got this was the only way that worked.
Your suggestion to use an object to group variables seems very promising though, I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried `this[dialogueVar]`... but upon
>   using `trace()` to test I get:  "**undefined**".

If your code is inside a Class (eg: not written on **Actions** panel), the simple fix is to declare variables first (as *public* or *private* vars) then can use them inside other functions without errors.

```
//# declare public variables (before using inside any later functions)
public var playerName :String = "";
public var dialogueLine :String ="";
```

> I want the functionality to replace text between double parenthesis, e.g. `((playerName))`, with the value of the variable specified in those parenthesis.

With the above fix, your own code attempt should work. Test `join` like this:

```
dialogueLine = dialogueLine.split("((" + dialogueVar + "))").join( this[dialogueVar] + "...!!");
```

Remember, whatever value gained using `dialogueVar =` must exist a public or private variable.

Finally, your example code should look something like this:

```
//# declare public variables (before using inside any functions)
public var playerName :String = "";
public var dialogueLine :String ="";

//# inside some fuction, update playerName with expected "Anon"...
playerName  = "Anon";

//# your problematic function now works like this...
function playFrame(frame:String):Function 
{
    return function(evt:Event = null):void
    {
        ...
        dialogueLine = dialogueText.text;
        //dialogueLine = "hello there, I see your name is ((playerName))";

        for(var i:int = 0; i < dialogueLine.split("((").length - 1; i++)
        {
            var dialogueVar:String = dialogueLine.substring(dialogueLine.indexOf("((") + 2, dialogueLine.indexOf("))"));
            dialogueLine = dialogueLine.split("((" + dialogueVar + "))").join( this[dialogueVar] + "...!!");

        }
        dialogueText.text = "";
        ...
    }
}
```

**PS:** If your code is on the timeline (Actions), then test this code to get an idea:

```
var playerName :String = "Anon";
var dialogueLine :String ="";
var str_Output :String = "";

dialogueLine = "hello there, I see your name is ((playerName))";

var dialogueVar:String = dialogueLine.substring(dialogueLine.indexOf("((") + 2, dialogueLine.indexOf("))"));

str_Output = dialogueLine.split("((" + dialogueVar + "))").join( this[dialogueVar] + "...!!");
trace ("str_Output : " + str_Output); //# check if expected...
```

Comment: This works yes, but the problem is that whatever is in between the double parenthesis has to be able to be other variables, like playerAge or whatever have you. In this way I'd have to create that huge switch statement for every variable I want to use, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I understand your problem better now. I've updated the Answer and added a **PS:** just in case your code doesn't accept `public` or `private` variables.